# Please advice on Storage Hardware ( NAS, SAN....)

Tags: storage, storage-area-network

Dear sirs, I would be moving to Storage team in a few weeks from my current Domain without any experience.

Kindly guide me and advise me how and what knowledge should I prepare to grab for this great technology, at least theoretically, before I hit the floor.

Could anyone guide me about what Hardware knowledge should I concentrate on and any sites or resources which I can look for?

Looking curiously for your guidance.

Am sorry if I have posted my query in the wrong forum.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 5):

This is totally dependent on what kind of systems your company has in place. If you don't know this, I would start by learning about Fibre Channel and iSCSI fundamentals, learn about the differences between the RAID levels and between DAS, NAS and SAN, just you have some basic terminology to start with.

Edit: I guess your superiors know that you don't have any storage experience. If not, don't try to 'fake' through your day, but be honest about your situation. Storage is an area where you can easily make costly and possible fatal mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with SvenW. If you have no experience, your best course of action will be to get in touch with whoever provides the SAN solution, and pay for an integration engineer to come onsite and set everything up for you. 
While the engineer is working, you can ask questions, take notes and learn as much as you can. What is really important is to make sure you have everything well documented

Answer (score 2):

If you peruse the [most popular SAN questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=san&sort=votes&pagesize=15) here on SF, you'll run into some terminology that should help out: deduplication, iSCSI, and a few real-world scenarios to get your feet wet.  I wouldn't worry too much about memorizing model names & statistics - I think if you're familiar with the terminology, you'll be able to follow conversations and present yourself as a motivated self-starter.

Good luck!